# Find properties of JS object with truthy values using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have an object like:

```
var foo = {
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    gamma: true
}
```

I can use _.findKey to get one key with a true value, but I'd really like to get an array containing all keys with a true value. E.g.

```
_.findAllKeys(foo, function(val) { return val; });
// yields -> ["alpha", "gamma"]
```

It's simple enough to write a function to do this, but it seems like such an obvious generalization of findKey that I feel I must just be missing it. Does lodash have such a function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```js
var foo = {
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    gamma: true
};

var t1 = _.keys(_.pick(foo, _.identity));
console.log(t1);

var t2 = _(foo).pick(_.identity).keys().value();
console.log(t2);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**
As noted by @backdesk, `_.pick` no longer works for lodash 4 because `_.pickBy` was split out.

```js
var foo = {
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    gamma: true
};

var t1 = _.keys(_.pickBy(foo, _.identity));
console.log(t1);

var t2 = _(foo).pickBy(_.identity).keys().value();
console.log(t2);

// _.pickBy defaults to _.identity

var t3 = _.keys(_.pickBy(foo));
console.log(t3);

var t4 = _(foo).pickBy().keys().value();
console.log(t4);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.8.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Side note and not  a criticism but this won't work using lodash if you were hoping for transparency - works with underscore. Use pickBy instead.

Comment: @backdesk Thank, I've updated the answer to note the difference between lodash 3 and 4.

Answer (score 11):

I found an answer which simultaneously feels kludgy and elegant.

```
var foo = {
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    gamma: true
};
_.invert(foo, true).true

// yields -> ["alpha", "gamma"]
```

Comment: Ouch. That's confusing. I'd probably just write a custom function which wraps the `_.invert(foo, true).true`, you only have to comment about what it's doing in one place. And you can make the function value more English.

Comment: This works, assuming you only want values that are literally `true`, and not all truthy values.

Comment: jsve Good call. I'd do that if I were using this more than one place. Retsam Indeed. In my case, this works, but it won't work for non-true-truthy values.

Comment: Does this still work? I get the string `"gamma"` only for this code now

Answer (score 5):

We can use pickBy() in lodash to get the key for which value equal to true.

```
const active = _.keys(_.pickBy(foo));
```

Alternatively we can also use,

```
var active = _.keys(foo).filter(function (id) {
    return foo[id]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy) in loDash by default uses `_.identity` to filter properties
so you can use it like this:

```
_.pickBy({'a': undefined, 'b':1, c:{}});

// => Object {b: 1, c: Object}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
var foo = {
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    gamma: true
}
```

_.pickBy(foo, _.identity);

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `pick` method.

> Return a copy of the object, filtered to only have values for the whitelisted keys (or array of valid keys). Alternatively accepts a predicate indicating which keys to pick.

```js
var foo = {
    alpha: true,
    beta: false,
    gamma: true
};

var picked = _.pick(foo, function(value) { return value; });
console.log(picked);

$('#output').html(JSON.stringify(picked));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the following - even though it is more verbose - because I think it is more obvious what it does. It requires es6 syntax, though:

```
_.toPairs(foo)
  .filter([key, value] => value)
  .map([key, value] => key);
```

---

If your ESLint does not allow unused variables you can for instance use the following in `.eslint.yml`:

```
rules:    
  no-unused-vars:
    - 2
    - vars: all
      args: after-used
      argsIgnorePattern: _$
```

Which allows to write

```
_.toPairs(foo)
  .filter([key_, value] => value)
  .map([key, value_] => key);
```